# Extending components from another ExtJS custom framework

Tags: javascript, inheritance, extjs, extend, extjs-mvc

I'm familiar with extending components within the same ExtJS MVC application, but now I'm wanting to use components from another ExtJS MVC application?  Can someone help me understand how this can be done and give an example of extending a component from App1 (MVC) in App2 (MVC)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use sencha cmd to [create a package](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/guide/command_packages) that is used by both applications and holds shared or common logic. Then each application can extend the components as needed.